# Jung : Fixing distance between vertices

Tags: java, jung

I am using Jung to draw a graph. In my case, a node can have both multiple parents and multiple child.

Since, a node can have multiple parents, I can not use a Tree layout to get my graph drawn as a Tree.

Thus, I am using a DAGLayout. However, in DAGLayout, the plotting is bottom-up.

To resolve this, I have rotated the graph 180 degrees to plot it from top to bottom.

Here is the code:

```
    // generate layout
    Layout<SimpleTaskDomain, Integer> layout = new DAGLayout<SimpleTaskDomain, Integer>(g);

    // fix layout size
    layout.setSize(new Dimension(700, 700));


    VisualizationViewer<SimpleTaskDomain, Integer> vv = new VisualizationViewer<SimpleTaskDomain, Integer>(layout);
    vv.setBackground(Color.white);
    vv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 800));
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller<SimpleTaskDomain>());

    Dimension d = layout.getSize();
    Point2D center = new Point2D.Double(d.width / 2, d.height / 2);
    vv.getRenderContext().getMultiLayerTransformer().getTransformer(Layer.LAYOUT).rotate(Math.PI, center);

    vv.setVertexToolTipTransformer(vv.getRenderContext().getVertexLabelTransformer());
    // vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeShapeTransformer(new
    // EdgeShape.Orthogonal<SimpleTaskDomain, Integer>());
    vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeShapeTransformer(new EdgeShape.Line<SimpleTaskDomain, Integer>());

    VertexFontTransformer<SimpleTaskDomain> vff = new VertexFontTransformer<SimpleTaskDomain>();
    vff.setBold(true);
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFontTransformer(vff);

    Transformer<SimpleTaskDomain, Paint> vertexPaint = new Transformer<SimpleTaskDomain, Paint>() {
        public Paint transform(final SimpleTaskDomain i) {
            return Color.GREEN;
        }
    };
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(vertexPaint);

    Transformer<SimpleTaskDomain, Shape> vertexSize = new Transformer<SimpleTaskDomain, Shape>() {
        public Shape transform(final SimpleTaskDomain i) {
            Rectangle2D.Double rectangle = new Rectangle2D.Double(-40, -20, 80, 40);
            return AffineTransform.getScaleInstance(2, 2).createTransformedShape(rectangle);
        }
    };

    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexShapeTransformer(vertexSize);

    vv.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Position.CNTR);
```

I am changing shape of the vertices to a rectangle instead of default circle.

However, in the output graph, the vertices are overlapping.

How can I control the distance between vertices such that the overlap does not happen.

I want a tree like structure with proper distance between the vertices.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Hi Vicky, 
I have the same situation as you,  a node can have both multiple parents and multiple child and I need to paint a Tree, so which impl of graph did you use in JUNG for this, also which layout at the end ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question says "DagLayout", but your code sample says "FRLayout".

In any event, DagLayout doesn't let you specify node distance.

I suggest you follow the general outline in MinimumSpanningTreeDemo:

(1) Extract the appropriate spanning tree from your graph.

(2) Lay out the spanning tree using TreeLayout (which allows you to specify spacing).

(3) Use the layout positions from the Tree Layout to create a new StaticLayout instance for your original graph, and visualize using that layout.

Comment: Sorry! was trying to see how the FR layout will look like and whether it will solve my problem... corrected the question... your point number 3... "Use the layout positions and so on... "... Does the MinimumSpanningTreeDemo show this ? Because on the output I see three graphs: KKLayout on the left (3 graphs).. Spanning Trees on top right (4 graphs) and original tree using TreeLayout (again 4 graphs)... But I want a single graph with all the vertices and edges between them and not multiple graphs.. is that possible... I apologize for the long comment!